# Access specific UITableViewCell in different UITableView within the navigation stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

i'm working on a tabbar application. Perhaps it's a trivial question, but i just simply want to replace the labelvalue of a UITableViewCell. I'm getting a NSString from a TextView, which is embedded within a UITableView "input". The Cell i want to modify is within the parentview of the "input" view.
The modification should take place in the save function.

```
 - (void)save:(id)sender
{   
    //Get the needed string
    DescriptionViewCell *cell = (DescriptionViewCell *) [descriptionTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[cell.textView text]];

    //Access parentview
    FindTableViewController *rootController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    UITableViewCell *descriptionCell = [rootController.findUITable cellForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection: 1]];

    //replace label string
    descriptionCell.textLabel.text = temp;
    [temp release];

    //return to parentview
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Unfortunately the descriptionCell does not contain any data and the modification does not take place. Do you see any issues in my code or should i "play" around with the indexes.
Thanks in advance.
Cheers,
Simon

Comment: Have you tried adding an NSLog statement and printing out the value of temp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i think you are getting nothing in descriptionCell because that cell was not visible at that time. cellForRowAtIndexPath return nil if cell is not visible. Look at the documentation-

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
Returns the table cell at the specified index path.
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
Parameters

indexPath

    The index path locating the row in the receiver.

Return Value

    An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

You can do this by managing text in some data structure and when you go back to previous view you call reloadData and check for that value in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
```

Comment: Thx, that did it. But the data has to be reloaded in the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: yes you have to call reloadData for table view in view will appear.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in your root table view controller add an `NSString` property which will be used store the value of the updated text. Then in your `save` method, update the value of that the root view controlelrs `NSString` property with the new text. Finally you call your root view controlles tableviews `reloadData` method like so:

```
FindTableViewController *rootController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[rootController.tableView reloadData];
```

In your root table view you want to impliment your table views `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method such that it applys the value of the NSSTring property to the appropriate cell when you call `reloadData`.

```
if(indexPath.row == myCellIndex){
     cell.textLabel.text = myStringProperty; 
}
```